# Easy way to extract multiple dates from string without spaces?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a way to automatically extract dates from a string, but following each other without a delimiter

For example my string is: `\n-\n24-04-201923-04-201922-04-201921-04-201920-04-201919-04-201918-04-2019`

How can I get this output:

```
24-04-2019
23-04-2019
22-04-2019
21-04-2019
20-04-2019
19-04-2019
18-04-2019
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that they're all of equal length, you can just clear the `\n`'s then use `textwrap`:

```py
import textwrap
print(textwrap.wrap(my_string, 10))
```

You can remove `\n`'s using `strip()`:

```py
my_string = my_string.strip()
```

Comment: I did not even think about that! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code also.

```py
string='\n-\n24-04-201923-04-201922-04-201921-04-201920-04-201919-04-201918-04-2019'
newStr=string[3:]
for char in range(0,len(newStr),10):
    print newStr[char:char+10]
```

Here's the output

```py
24-04-2019
23-04-2019
22-04-2019
21-04-2019
20-04-2019
19-04-2019
18-04-2019
```